# Pointing to first element of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, element

I'm sorry if this questions has already been asked, I searched a bit before posting, but couldn't find an answer to it.

I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define ESC 27

typedef struct{
    int data[10];
    int n;
} tlist;

void menu(){
    printf("Options:\n");
    printf("1) Show list\n");
    printf("ESC) Quit\n");
}

void showList(tlist *list){
    int *p;
    p = &list->data[0];
    if(list->n == 0){
        printf("Empty list!\n\n");
    }else{
        for(int i=0; i<list->n; i++){
            printf("%d \n", *p);
            p++;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char choice;
    tlist list;
    list.n = 10;

    list.data[0] = 16;  
    list.data[1] = 17;
    list.data[2] = 18;
    list.data[3] = 19;
    list.data[4] = 20;
    list.data[5] = 21;
    list.data[6] = 22;
    list.data[7] = 23;
    list.data[8] = 24;
    list.data[9] = 25;
    do{
        menu();
        scanf("%s",&choice);
            switch(choice){
                case '1': showList(&list);
                    break;
                case ESC:
                    printf("quiting...\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Invalid Choice!\n");
                    break;      
            }
    }while(choice != ESC);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program I have this output:

0 
17 
18 
19 
20 
21 
22 
23 
24 
25

I can't understand why the first print is the position of the first element in the array and not the first element itself. Can someone please explain me?

Comment: `scanf("%s",&choice);` - that's wrong. `choice` is a single char.

Comment: Well, this part of the code is working anyway.

Comment: No, it's not. It sort of looks like it is but in fact you have undefined behavior.

Comment: Mat, you were right. Changed it for %c and it worked. But the code is giving me 2 outputs now:

16 
17 
18 
19 
20 
21 
22 
23 
24 
25 
Choose option:
1) Show list
ESC) Quit
Invalid option!

Comment: `char choice;` does not go with `scanf("%s",&choice);` or even with `scanf("%s",choice);` which expects an array. I suggest `scanf(" %c", &choice);` note the space before `%c` because [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

Comment: (" %c", &choice) worked perfectly! Thank you Mat and Vane for the explanation!

Comment: probable UB explanation: when you enter a 1 for the wrong `"%s"` in scanf, it may write the string (`"%s"`) null terminator to `list.data[0]` overwriting the initial 16.

Comment: gr0gu3, What compiler are you using that does not warn about `char choice;...
        scanf("%s",&choice);`?

Comment: @chux gcc -Wall does not give a warning. I doubt that it should: Since variable ``choice'' is a char, &choice matches the format string "%s", methinks.

Comment: @chux I use GCC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`choice` is a `char` and the correct conversion specifier to be used in `scanf` is `c` and not `s`.

One must also be careful when using `scanf` interspersed with `printf` statements which print new lines (`\n`).

When `scanf` has the conversion specifier `c`, then it will interpret any whitespace as a character and will not wait for the actual input. So the `scanf` here should make allowance for the whitespace character by including a leading blank space.

So the `scanf` statement should be:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

It is also a good practice to check the return value of `scanf` before proceeding further in the program. As per the standard, `scanf` returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.